# Round function query 2 to 3 arguments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to find the revenue per distinct user in this query but seem to be running in this error.

```
select concat('$',format(cast(round(sum(total)/count(distinct(customers))),2) 
as int),N'N','en-US') 
from table
```

My error:

> The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments

Comment: select concat('$',format(cast(round(sum(total)/count(distinct(customers)),2) 
as int),N'N','en-US') 
from table  

you need to add how much you want to round by for instance here I used 2

Comment: `FORMAT` is quite capable of rounding on its own. Ex. `select FORMAT(2349345.439, 'C', 'en-US')` formats the value directly as currency, complete with separators. `select FORMAT(2349345.439, 'N2', 'en-US')` rounds to two decimals. `select FORMAT(2349345.439, '$0.00', 'en-US')` gives the value without thousands separators. And if you really want to truncate digits (as your `CAST` seems to imply) then `ROUND`ing to two digits first isn't useful...

Comment: @Jake-Wagner - If You need rounded result -  be carefull - `select FORMAT(convert(int,round(2.900,2)), 'N2', 'en-US')`  and `select FORMAT(round(2.900,0), 'N2', 'en-US')` yield different results - `2.00` and `3.00` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you mean:

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(SUM(Total)/COUNT(DISTINCT customers),2) AS int),N'N'),'en-US') 
FROM [table];
```

But, really, worry about the formatting of your values in your presentation layer (The `FORMAT` and `CONCAT` don't need to be there).

Also, Why `ROUND({expr},2)` and then `CAST({expr} AS int)`? Why not `ROUND({expr},0)`?

Answer (score 1):

For instance used 2 as length to round

```
round(sum(total)/count(distinct(customers)),2)
```